# Where do free electrons come from?

Tags: electrons

Here's what I what to know... Atoms have a nucleus that's positively charged and the negative electrons flow around it. Well when you pull the negative electrons off the atom where do the new electrons come from? Why does copper not ever run out of electrons? Who is making the new negative electrons? I hope you see what I'm saying and give me an answer. Thanks ... Won't copper run out free of electrons?

Comment: You can check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity

Comment: Who told you that copper does not ever run out of electrons? See in Wikipedia explanations about $$CuSO_4$$ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate. In this molecule, the Cu atom donates electrons to the chemical radica $SO_4$. A example simpler to me to explain is $$Cu_2O$$ in which each copper atom donates its electron on the last shell, to the oxygen atom which is "hungry" for 2 electrons to complete it last shell.

Answer (score 6):

In order for a [current](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current) to flow steadily, you have to connect the conductor (copper in your case) to positive and negative poles of a battery. Then the electrons go from the copper to the positive pole of the battery - but - they are replaced by the electrons which come from the negative pole of the battery. Thus, the free electrons in copper are only needed to make it possible for current to flow, the copper itself is not depleted of electrons.

Answer (score 0):

The number of electrons in a chunk of metal is very large, however, one can only remove (or add) relatively few, before the metal becomes so highly charged, that its potential exceeds the limits of any practical isolation. If we could remove all the electrons in the conduction band, the metal would probably disintegrate.

Answer (score 0):

This analogy might aid some insight:

Think of cell in the circuit as a water pump that is constantly pumping water from a tank at the ground to the tank at any higher height, (say first floor). Now, put a tap on the tank at first floor and let the water flow continuously out of there into the tank at the ground, in between you may use use the flowing water to wash hands or do anything except consume water.

In this situation the higher tank never runs out of water even though the water is constantly flowing out of tap.

Same goes with the electrical circuit. The same electrons continuously flow in the closed path of conductors hence electrons are never used of nor does any conductor run out of free electrons.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the situation, if 1)the copper is in a circuit as a conductor or 2)you are really separating the electrons from the whole solid or making them bounded to the atoms(by adding some impurities for example) or 3) some other processes takes place.

if you mean the first case: the answer is that as a conductor in a circuit the separated electrons are replaced due to the current... explain your question more, please.

Answer (score -1):

It only needs pressure ( CU atoms ) to flow the free electrons by using electro magnetic inductor, and the same electrons will go back and forth with AC current or DC ( battery), thus Copper atoms never loose its electron.